# Winforms WebBrowser control - Windows 10

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I set the following features for my web browser control in my Windows Forms Application (framework 4.5.2):

FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION to 1101 FEATURE_WEBOC_ENABLE_HTTP2 to 1 and so on (all from regedit parameters in IE)

But I want it to run on my current operating system (windows 10).

When I go to: https://www.whatismybrowser.com/ in the web browser control it says: Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 8

How can I get it simulate on windows 10? I need it for compatibility purpose. Thank you.

Comment: What is sent in user agent?

Comment: If you add the standard `User-Agent` header (`"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"`) using the `Navigate()` method overload (or a custom WebBrowser), you should get that result.

Comment: Thank you so much @Jimi it works! :) you're the best